# ¿Cómo subir fotos con PHP y AngularJS?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Buenas de nuevo. Resulta que ahora me encargaron subir dos fotos en AngularJS y PHP, un logo normal y otro minimizado. Entonces me gustaría una ayuda para saber cómo hacer la subida sin mayores complicaciones.

Estoy usando el Plugin **["FileInput Bootstrap"](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo)**.

**app.js:**

```
.controller('miEmpresaCtrl', function($scope, Connect, $http, $rootScope){
  $scope.changes_saved = false;
  $.AdminLTE.layout.fix()
  $("#commerce_logo").fileinput('refresh');
  $("#commerce_minimized_logo").fileinput('refresh');
  $("#commerce_logo").fileinput({
      uploadUrl:service_api,
      showRemove:false,
      showUpload:false,
      dropZoneEnabled:false,
      uploadExtraData:function(){
        return {
          service:"setCommerceData",
          token: token,
          name : $rootScope.commerce[0].company_name,
          description: $rootScope.commerce[0].company_description,
        }
      }
    });
  $scope.saveChanges = function(){
    $('#commerce_logo').fileinput('upload');
    $scope.changes_saved = true;  
  }
})
```

**services.php:**

```
if($_POST['service'] == "setCommerceData"){
        if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
            $tmp_logo = $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
            $name_logo = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
            print_r($name_logo);
            $uploadPathLogo = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name_logo ;
            move_uploaded_file( $tmp_logo, $uploadPathLogo );
            $uploadPathMinLogo = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name_minlogo ;
            move_uploaded_file( $tmp_minlogo, $uploadPathMinLogo );
            $idCompany = json_decode(decrypt(base64_decode($_POST["token"]), $clave))->company;
            die(json_encode(setCommerceData($mysqli, $idCompany, $_POST['name'],$_POST['description'], $uploadPathLogo, $uploadPathMinLogo), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
        }
    }
```

**commerce.html:**

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3 class="title-top">
                Mi Empresa
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-warning">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Información General</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="commerce_name">Nombre de empresa:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="commerce_name" ng-model="commerce[0].company_name" placeholder="Nombre de empresa" ng-model="commerce_name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="commerce_logo">Url de Logo:</label>
                            <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" data-preview-file-type="text" name="logo" class="form-control" id="commerce_logo"  ng-model="commerce[0].company_logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="commerce_logo">Url Logo Minimizado:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="min_logo" class="form-control" data-preview-file-type="text" id="commerce_minimized_logo"  ng-model="commerce[0].company_minimized_logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="commerce_description">Descripción:</label>
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="commerce_description" ng-model="commerce[0].company_description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-if="changes_saved">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        Cambios <strong>guardados</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-info" ng-click="saveChanges()">Guardar Cambios</div>
</section>
```

Cualquier ayuda o dato se agradece...

Comment: En angular es medio especial . Te sugiero hacer un formulario html y subir la foto con PHP y lo muestras con angularJs . Acá hay códig que hice que te puede ayudar: https://github.com/juanitourquiza/empleados

Answer (score 0):

Haz la subida con xhr tradicional, en el siguiente ejemplo al servidor te llegarían los ficheros en un array llamado files.

```
private _xhr(method: string = 'POST', url: string, headers: Object, body = null, files: File[] = []): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {

      const formData = new FormData();
      const params = body || {};

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files[]", files[i], files[i].name);
      }

      Object.keys(params).forEach( key => formData.append(key, params[key]) );

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            observer.complete();
          } else {
            observer.error(xhr.response);
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.open(method, url, true);
      Object.keys(headers).forEach( key => xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]) );
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```